# Loading the deployment manager for a jumphost in GCP project

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to solve the challenge lab for Qwicklabs 'Cloud Architecture' . The lab presents a scenario where it is specified that the cloud architect for a project has written the Deployment Manager configuration to build the network for project's production environment. They say i can find the DM configuration on my **jumphost in /work/dm**. They ask to create the network using the Deployment Manager configuration (/work/dm/prod-network.yaml and /work/dm/prod-network.jinja).
I am not able to load the configuration files.
Any hep?

Comment: "I am not able to load" - what exact error do you receive? How exactly are you loading: with `git clone`, `wget`, `curl`? Is this you CloudShell instance in Qwiklabs? Provide some more details please. Also, you can chat with Qwiklabs support from within the Qwiklabs web page.

Comment: I don't know from where and how to load the files. Can u plz suggest a command?

Comment: You should follow step-by-step instruction in the lab. In the beginning of the lab you could see the general description of what resources are pre-configured for you, and what you should create yourself. More likely you have to use one of the commands i've mentioned in the previous comment. Those should be part of the Lab tasks.

Comment: Actually its a challenge lab and there are no step by step instructions. I know how to copy the deployment files from github to a local directory. But what if they say the DM files are on jumphost? I am unable to understand that.

Comment: Step back for a minute. The purpose of a Qwiklabs Challenge Lab is for you to test your knowledge. You should already know how to do this. Asking us to help you is cheating yourself. Go back to the other Qwiklabs and learn how to do this for yourself. Your goal is to be able to do this challenge without asking for any help.

Comment: This question should be deleted as it involves copyrighted work of Qwiklabs.

Comment: Sir sorry if m breaking rules...but in other lab, the deployment manager was copied from a GitHub. I was just trying to get some hint about how to download the same from a jumphost. I m not expecting someone to post the solution. Apologies if this is against the rules of Qwicklabs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the vm instance. There is an instance named kraken-jumphost connect to it via SSH.

Do

```
cd ..
```

2 times till you come out of home directory and you will find the work folder there

Answer (score 0):

> They say i can find the DM configuration on my **jumphost** in /work/dm.

1. You should check if there is a host or VM instance with a name containing  `jumphost`.
2. Connect to this host via SSH: using `SSH` button in GCP Console GUI or
   with `gcloud compute ssh ip_addr_or_hostname --zone zonename` in CloudShell.
3. Seek for the `/work/dm/` directory on that host.

Comment: yes i am aware that the project consists of a virtual machine named  kraken-jumpost. It does not have an external IP address. Still i tried to connect via SSH as you suggested.I used the command like this-  $gcloud compute ssh kraken-jumphost --zone us-east1-b

Comment: and after that                                                                                                          $gcloud compute scp --recurse student-00-09a0bfdd4df@qwiklabs.net@kraken-jumphost/work/dm/prod-network.yaml student-00-09a0bfdd4df@qwiklabs.net@kraken-jumphost/dp --zone useast1-b.                               dp is a local directory i made. But i am getting an error- "Sources must be remote when destination is local" Got source: [student-00-09a0bfdd4df@qwiklabs.net@kraken-jumphost/work/dm/prod-network.yaml] destination: student-00-09a0bfdd4df@qwiklabs.net@kraken-jumphost/dp